# zmq.Poller not receiving any messages in Python

Tags: python, zeromq

This is the code I'm using to receive zmq messages:

```
poller = zmq.Poller()
for socket, event in poller.poll(0):
    if socket is my_sock:
        my_sock = messaging.recv_one(socket).my_data
print(my_sock.status)
```

It works in other files in the project I'm working on, however, in this specific file it doesn't receive anything. I tried placing a print statement in the for loop and it failed to print anything at all. Any tips on why this is? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I got my socket from the poller, I failed to call the data correctly.

What I used:

```
my_sock.status
```

What I needed to call:

```
my_sock.MyStruct.status
```

I simply forgot to call the name of the structure in which I instantiated my variables in `log.capnp`:

```
struct MyStruct{
  status @0 :Bool;
  speed @1 :Float32;
  angle @2 :Float32;
  time @3 :Float32;
}
```